# Error "cannot locate xindy module for language persian in codepage utf8" in making glossary

Tags: glossaries, xindy

I'm trying to make a glossary in my document.

My glossary is not printed and it's an empty page.
To compile the glossary I read that I had to make a custom user command in TexMaker:

```bsh
xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.glg -o %.gls %.glo
xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.blg -o %.bls %.blo
xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.alg -o %.acr %.acn
```

But, when I run this command I get this error:

> cannot locate xindy module for language persian in codepage utf8

So, I looked at this directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\xindy\xindy\lang` and checked that the Persian folder exists.

I don't have any idea what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem fixed.
That was because of my xindy version.
I just changed the command to this:

```
 xindy -L persian -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.glg -o %.gls %.glo |
 xindy -L persian -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.blg -o %.bls %.blo | 
 xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.alg -o %.acr %.acn
```

and it works fine.