# No Persian language in xindy/lang directory

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, xindy, xepersian, persian

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and TeX Live 2015/Debian. To make a glossary for my document, my template uses `xindy` package. I installed it using:

```
sudo apt install xindy
```

When I try to compile it, the following error I get.

> Cannot locate xindy module for language persian in codepage utf8.

I checked out the `/usr/share/xindy/lang` directory and found there's no directory for Persian language.

How should I install it? Should I update my TeX distribution?

---

**Update #1**

Output of `xindy --version`

```
xindy release: unknown
xindy script version: 1.16
xindy kernel version: 3.0
CLISP version 2.49 (2010-07-07) (built on brownie.buildd [127.0.1.1])
    architecture: X86_64
```

Comment: Did you see [Error “cannot locate xindy module for language persian in codepage utf8” in making glossary](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219817/14500)?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, in that question OP is using Windows and the Persian directory exists, but my situation differs a bit. I'm using Ubuntu and that directory doesn't exist.

Comment: The `xindy` package of Ubuntu provides an old version of xindy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit) mentioned in his comment, `xindy` of Ubuntu repositories is not the latest version and should be updated to resolve the issue.

The following repo contains the latest version, so you should first add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then update `xindy` and `xindy-rules`.

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main
```

Once you're done, you can safely remove this repo from the sources file.

P.S: [Mirrors](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/xindy-rules/download) are also available.