# Cannot locate xindy module for language british in codepage utf8

Tags: babel, languages, xindy, glossaries-extra

When I use `xindy` for as my `makeglossaries` backend, I get the following warning:

> Cannot locate xindy module for language british in codepage utf8

However, there is no issue with the typesetting of the glossaries themselves (to my eyes everything look ok).

I saw a similar question for the Persian language [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219817/error-cannot-locate-xindy-module-for-language-persian-in-codepage-utf8-in-maki), but I do not need support for any exotic languages other than UK English. I am using `latexmk` which calls `makeglossaries` through a custom subdependency-style function.

What does this warning mean, and how can I get rid of it? I am using `luatex`

Here is the MWE (`main.tex`) that produces this warning (please also see the `latexmkrc` files used to run this) :

```
\RequirePackage{shellesc}
\RequirePackage[debrief]{silence}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none, citestyle=numeric-comp, maxbibnames=50, url=true, doi=true, eprint=false,backref=true,backrefstyle=three]{biblatex} % seems to have strong dependence on csquotes?
\usepackage[luatex,paper=a4paper,hmarginratio=1:1, vmarginratio=1:1, scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % important to load before fontspec
\usepackage{lualatex-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[frac,vfrac,multskip]{mathfixs}
\usepackage{setspace} % Define line spacing
\usepackage{fontspec} % load after graphicx
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon}]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional},Ligatures={TeX, Common%, Historic, Contextual, Rare, Discretionary
}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Latin Modern Mono}
\usepackage{ragged2e} %  "The package should be loaded after the body font and size have been established  for example, after font packages have been loaded

\setmathfont[bold-style=ISO]{Libertinus Math} % https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus/issues/20
\setmathfont[range={\mathunder,\triangleq,\underbrace},Scale=MatchUppercase]{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage[british]{babel} % with british, we get OUP hyphenation material for free
\usepackage[final,activate={true,nocompatibility},factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10,babel=true]{microtype} % if using option babel=true, babel must be loaded before microtype
\usepackage[british]{selnolig} % if using babel, this package should go after loading babel
\usepackage[newfloat=true]{minted}
\usepackage[minted,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{csquotes} % The fvextra package is loaded by minted, so you should load minted before csquotes

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,automake,xindy]{glossaries-extra}% should be loaded after hyperref % consider 'symbols' package option

\makeglossaries
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{nohyperfirst}{true}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short} % applicable only for glossaries-extra.sty
\newacronym{adc}{ADC}{Analog to Digital Converter}

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Acronyms}]\label{ch:glossary} % basic style
This is some random text which uses \glspl{adc}.
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

This is my `latexmkrc`

```
push @generated_exts, "acn";
push @generated_exts, "acr";
push @generated_exts, "alg";
push @generated_exts, "auxlock";
push @generated_exts, "brf";
push @generated_exts, "cb";
push @generated_exts, "cb2";
push @generated_exts, "glg-abr";
push @generated_exts, "glo-abr";
push @generated_exts, "gls-abr";
push @generated_exts, "ist";
push @generated_exts, "nav";
push @generated_exts, "nlg";
push @generated_exts, "nlo";
push @generated_exts, "nls";
push @generated_exts, "nmo";
push @generated_exts, "run.xml";
push @generated_exts, "slg";
push @generated_exts, "snm";
push @generated_exts, "spl";
push @generated_exts, "syg";
push @generated_exts, "syi";
push @generated_exts, "synctex.gz";
push @generated_exts, "tar.gz";
push @generated_exts, "tdo";
push @generated_exts, "thm";
push @generated_exts, "loa";
push @generated_exts, "mypyg";
push @generated_exts, "mtc*";
push @generated_exts, "ptc";
push @generated_exts, "synctex*";
push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';


$pdflatex = 'lualatex %O %S --interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error --shell-escape --bibtex --recorder';
$pdf_mode = 4;
$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';


@cus_dep_list = (@cus_dep_list, "glo-abr gls-abr 0 makenomenclature");
sub makenomenclature {
   system("makeindex $_[0].glo-abr -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].gls-abr"); }

@cus_dep_list = (@cus_dep_list, "syi syg 0 makegls");
sub makegls {
   system("makeindex $_[0].syg -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].syi"); }

add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "makeglossaries -q '$_[0]'";
  }
  else {
    system "makeglossaries '$_[0]'";
  };
}

sub asy {return system("asy -o \"$_[0]\" \"$_[0]\"");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");

push @file_not_found, '^Package .* No file `([^\\\']*)\\\'';

$bibtex_use=2
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `makeglossaries` should map `british` to `english`. What version are you using? (Check the `.log` file for `glossaries.sty` version and run `makeglossaries --version` for the `makeglossaries` version.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I am using makeglossaries Version `4.41 (2018-07-23)`, glossaries-extra `2018/08/18 v1.36 (NLCT)`, and glossaries `2018/07/23 v4.41 (NLCT)` installed with `TL2018` base and regularly updated using `tlmgr`.  Is this a bug in the package(s)?

Comment: @Krishna It works fine for the following: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[british]{babel} \usepackage[xindy]{glossaries} \makeglossaries \newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={}} \begin{document} \gls{sample} \printglossary \end{document}` (and also with `glossaries-extra`) so you need to provide a MWE that produces your warning.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Ah. Indeed. It seems to work with your MWE. I am maybe looking at a package conflict or something. Shall debug a bit more before posting back.

Comment: @Krishna Quick check: are you sure you're using `makeglossaries` not `makeglossaries-lite`? The light-weight Lua version doesn't use any mappings.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot yes. I am using the full perl-version of `makeglossaries`.

Comment: Can you add the `latexmk` custom dependency to your question?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Yes, absolutely. Sorry for prematurely posting the question.  I am working on isolating the issue and shall post a complete MWE along with my `latexmkrc` here in less than 15 minutes.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thank you for your patience. I tried removing most of the clutter in my preamble, but the problem persists. Whilst I continue to cut down on unnecesssary packages, I have updated the question with the pruned preamble thus far, along with my `latexmkrc`. Can you please have a look at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `automake` package option, which means that the `glossaries` package will try to run `xindy` using TeX's shell escape. This will fail in restricted mode, since `xindy` isn't on the restricted list, but your `latexmk` code indicates that you are running LuaLaTeX with `--shell-escape`, which switches to the unrestricted mode and allows `xindy` to be run from TeX.

The `automake` option doesn't have the full features of `makeglossaries` and doesn't provide the `babel` dialect to `xindy` language mappings, so it runs `xindy` with `-L british`, which isn't recognised. Your `latexmk` dependencies then run `makeglossaries` which also calls `xindy`, but this time with `-L english`, so the correct files are then generated.

So the warning most likely comes from the shell escape call to `xindy` not from the `makeglossaries` call to `xindy`. The simplest solution is to remove the `automake` option and leave the `xindy` call to `makeglossaries`. If you really want to use `automake` instead of `makeglossaries`, then you need to specify the correct `xindy` language name:

```
\usepackage[automake,xindy={language=english}]{glossaries}
```

(Likewise for `glossaries-extra`.) Note that running TeX in the unrestricted mode is a security risk, so if you don't absolutely need it, it's better to remove `--shell-escape` and `automake` and just run `makeglossaries` from outside of TeX.

Unrelated: your `latexmk` seems to be mixing `glossaries` with `nomencl`. The `nomencl.ist` file is for use with the `nomencl` package, but the `nomencl` package uses `.nlo` and `.nls` as the file extensions. The `glossaries-extra` package uses `.glo-abr` and `.gls-abr` (for abbreviations).

Answer (score 2):

`xindy` does not recognize `british` as a language.

```
$ texindy -L british -C utf8 testtemp.idx
Cannot locate xindy module for language british in codepage utf8.

$ texindy -L english -C utf8 testtemp.idx
Opening logfile "/dev/null" (done)
Reading indexstyle...
[cut lines]
Finished processing index.

Writing markup... [10%] [20%] [30%] [40%] [50%] [60%] [70%] [80%] [90%] [100%]
Markup written into file "./testtemp.ind".
```

With test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Comments on Foo\index{Foo}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

and having done one `pdflatex` run.

I don't know how `makeglossaries` ends up (perhaps!) using `-L british` here.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I also think the same. Nicola seems to think that `british` should map to `english` .  Maybe this is a bug in the package?

Comment: Can you add the Latexmk sub-functions you are using in latexmkrc for running `makeglossaries`? @NicolaTalbot is author of `makeglossaries` so she will much better than me comment on this...

Comment: Yes, I shall do that. Hope you don't mind if I steal your MWE and modify my question to add a complete set of information?

Comment: go ahead, my answer will get superseded certainly by others in future